# Кросплатформенный код на C, теоретические проблемы

Tags: c, кроссплатформенность

Понимаю что вопрос дурацкий, но тем не менее :) В каких случаях *неверно* утверждение: "если код на pure C, использующий только стандартные библиотеки, собирается и работает под linux-32, linux-64 и win-32, то он без дополнительных мер соберётся и корректно заработает под win64"?

В принципе ответ очевиден: например, в тех случаях, где есть завязка на разрядность, совмещённая с "*ифдеф виндовс*". Но есть практические примеры не таких очевидных вещей?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже было сказано выше, многое зависит не только от платформы, но и от компилятора - часто именно от компилятора.

Для разрешения ситуаций с размерами и разрядностью иногда создаются внутренние типы, фактический смысл которых зависит от платформы. Так например у Apple CGFloat в 32-битной системе это float, а в 64-битной - double.

Для пущей совместимости могу посоветовать собирать проект одним и тем же компилятором на разных платформах.

Comment: Под Windows исходники могут собираться разными компиляторами, если надумается выложить их.

Comment: Пишите рекомендации, часто авторы библиотек не придают этому значения. Кроме того, грамотно написанный код не должен зависеть от размера типов, для чего используется sizeof(type). А другие конструкции и библиотеки должны работать одинаково. Проблема может возникнуть при использовании аппаратно-специфичных конструкций.

Comment: Из системных вещей - низкоуровневая работа с сокетами, но тут вроде всё облазил. Ещё задействована сторонняя библиотека, которая очень любит "грязные хаки" при работе с памятью (типичный пример: `void *mem = (((void *)*vec) - sizeof(struct __dvhdr));`). Вот с ней пришлось повозиться, да...

Comment: И чем же этот пример страшен?

Comment: @klopp это не грязный хак, а работа с памятью. А работа с памятью в принципе требует аккуратности. Собственно из-за того, что Си позволяет делать что угодно с памятью, и удобен и опасен одновременно.

Comment: Он не то чтобы страшен. Но, например, не все компиляторы его лопают (`dlib\dvector.c(27): Error! Cannot perform operation with pointer to void` etc)

Answer (score 3):

Ну, например вы используете тип long, который имеет разный размер на разных платформах, и приводите его к другому типу (к указателю)

```
      OS           arch           size
Windows       IA-32        4 bytes
Windows       Intel 64     4 bytes
Windows       IA-64        4 bytes
Linux         IA-32        4 bytes
Linux         Intel 64     8 bytes
Linux         IA-64        8 bytes
Mac OS X      IA-32        4 bytes
Mac OS X      Intel 64     8 bytes
```

Visual C, Win32:

```
sizeof(char)=1
sizeof(wchar_t)=2
sizeof(short)=2
sizeof(int)=4
sizeof(long)=4
sizeof(long long)=8
sizeof(void*)=4
sizeof(size_t)=4
```

Visual C, Win64:

```
sizeof(char)=1
sizeof(wchar_t)=2
sizeof(short)=2
sizeof(int)=4
sizeof(long)=4
sizeof(long long)=8
sizeof(void*)=8
sizeof(size_t)=8
```

GCC on 32 platform:

```
sizeof(char)=1
sizeof(wchar_t)=4
sizeof(short)=2
sizeof(int)=4
sizeof(long)=4
sizeof(long long)=8
sizeof(void*)=4
sizeof(size_t)=4
```

GCC on 64 platform:

```
sizeof(char)=1
sizeof(wchar_t)=4
sizeof(short)=2
sizeof(int)=4
sizeof(long)=8
sizeof(long long)=8
sizeof(void*)=8
sizeof(size_t)=8
```

Comment: Про разрядность понятно, ага.

Comment: @klopp, реально (с учетом перечисленных в вопросе архитектур) здесь важно, что разрядность long и указателя не совпадают.

Answer (score 1):

Довольно часто код полагается на undefined behaviour, и таким образом зависит от конкретной реализации компилятора.

Популярной ошибкой является вызов метода, не использующего локальные переменные, по `NULL`-указателю. Это *может* сработать на некоторых платформах, но по стандарту это имеет право привести к чему угодно.

То же относится к [переполнению *знакового* целого](https://blog.regehr.org/archives/213). GNU toolchain под интеловской платформой доопределяет поведение в этом случае, но другие компиляторы — нет.

---

Более тонкая ошибка: *чтение* неинициализированной переменной есть UB по стандарту. Очень многие забывают это, считая, что она будет содержать «какое-то там значение», и ничего страшного в обращении к ней нет. Однако, на платформе IA64 (Itanium) это [может привести к крешу](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040119-00/?p=41003).

Comment: В подобных случаях полезно выставлять флаг компилятору "считать ворнинги ошибками"

Comment: @George: Не помогает. Возможное UB чересчур часто встречается в коде. Например: `char access(char* p, int idx) { return p[idx]; }`. Тут _возможно_ UB — вы согласны на warning? В статье по ссылке из ответа более хорошие примеры.

Comment: я не уверен, что он тут в принципе выдаст ворнинг. здесь необходима проверка корректности входных параметров

Comment: Вопрос скорее не в компиляторе и платформе, а в программисте.

Comment: Ну, иницализация давно на уровне рефлексов. А с выявлением многих случаев UB неплохо справляется cppcheck. Что характерно, на кроссплатформенный код, который создавался в Windows, у него ругани, как правило, больше, чем наоборот :)